# TimerListener issues in Sip Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, sip, servlet-listeners

In order to use servlet timers, I have to use the TimerListener interface. When I'm deploying my application, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No TimerListener is configured.
```

I have declared my implementation class in a listener element of the Sip deployment descriptor (sip.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sip-app  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet/sip-app_1_1.xsd"
      version="1.1">
  <listener>
     <listener-class>net.sip.psngn.NaerumPoliceSipServlet</listener-class>
  </listener>
</sip-app>
```

The error occurs exactly when I'm creating my servlet timer. Does anyone know how to solve this ?. Thanks in advance.

```
package net.sip.psngn;

import javax.servlet.sip.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.sql.Time;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipListener;


@javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipServlet
@SipListener
public class NaerumPoliceSipServlet extends SipServlet implements TimerListener  {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 3978425801979081269L;

public String CSeq;

@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Resource
private UserTransaction utx;

@Resource
TimerService timerservice;

/*
 * Demonstrates extension with a new "REPUBLISH" method
 */
@Override
protected void doRequest(SipServletRequest reqfromclient) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    if( reqfromclient.getMethod().equals("MESSAGE") ) {
        String MsgContent = reqfromclient.getContent().toString();
        System.out.println("The arrived message is " + MsgContent);



        // Assign the callee URI
        String URICallee = reqfromclient.getTo().getURI().toString();


        String reqDomain = ((SipURI)reqfromclient.getTo().getURI()).getHost();

         //Assign the caller URI
        String URICaller = reqfromclient.getFrom().getURI().toString();

        //Get the sequence of arriving MESSAGE
        CSeq = reqfromclient.getHeader("CSeq");
        System.out.println("Sequence number of the message "+CSeq);

        // Get the application session of the message
        SipApplicationSession sas = reqfromclient.getApplicationSession();

        System.out.println("The app session is: " + sas);



        // Create the timer with a timeout after 20 seconds
        ServletTimer servlettimer = timerservice.createTimer(sas, 20000, false, "enough");

        System.out.println("The Servlet Timer is created and delay is set to 20 seconds");

       //Store the ID of the timer as an attribute of the SipApplicationSession
        sas.setAttribute("TimerID", servlettimer.getId());


        System.out.println("TimerID: " + servlettimer.getId());

        // Access the stopwatch from the other class
        StopwatchClass stwclass = new StopwatchClass();
        //Get the message arrival time
        Time time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
    }

    public void timeout(ServletTimer servlettimer) {
       if ("enough".equals(servlettimer.getInfo())) {
         System.out.println(servlettimer.getApplicationSession()); 
       }
    }



}
```

Comment: What SIP Servlet container are you using? Suggest editing your question to include this info so the appropriate experts may answer it. Also it looks like your class wouldn't compile since it does not include the `timeout` method.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include my timeout method before, but it is implemented inside my class (edited now). I'm using the Sailfin SIP application server.